# Loading a directive only after a login event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `<menu>` directive on the main page, which also has a `<view>`

The view is what contains the login page and the menu is just hidden. This means that the menuController is loading before login, but I need it to refresh or load After login (using loginController) because of dependent variables, such as name and isAdmin.

I've read about $watch but we're not using scope, I'm using controller as syntax so I'm not sure that worked

Comment: Menu into an Iframe??

Comment: `<my-directive ng-if="isLogged"></my-directive>` Something like this?

Comment: your menu is loaded by jquery? You can try to convert your menu in a json object, and then, use angular to renderize the menu after returns from login.

Comment: Have you considered creating UserService which takes care of logging in. Then use this service in loginController and menu directive to show or hide menu and share user details (name, isAdmin).

Comment: Here is very robust example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9491/